# How to iterate many arrays simultaniously inside a same loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new with `thymeleaf`, and I want to display 3 values from 3 different arrays with the same index, inside the same `div.row`, I tried several ways but I only could iterate one array at a time without errors, below is my Controller side:

```
public String  index(Model model) {

  String[] table0 = {"0","1","2","3"}
  String[] table1 = {"14","21","25","75"}
  String[] table2 = {"7","63","57","87"}

  model.addAttribute("table0", table0;
  model.addAttribute("table1", table1);
  model.addAttribute("table2", table2);

  return "index";
}
```

Inside the html file, `table0` is the first array iterated without errors, I don't know how to **edit/improve** the following code to display all the three arrays `tables0`, `tables1` and `tables3` at the same time:

```
<div class="row" th:each="v0 : ${tables0}" >
    <div class="cell" th:text="value">
        <!-- Here I could display a value from tables0 -->
    </div>
    <div class="cell"  >
        <!-- Here I need to display the value of tables1 having the same index as v0 -->
    </div>
    <div class="cell"  >
        <!-- Here I need to display the value of tables2 having the same index as v0 -->                        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to split the logic into threads.

Comment: Your problem would be so much simpler if you had only one array and each index in that one array has an object with the three values in it.

Comment: @Gimby  is it the only way to do that?

Comment: @SPlatten How would I do that?

Comment: @MiraSoft, you mentioned Java in your  post, google "Java thread tutorial" or go here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Comment: @MiraSoft of course it is not the only way to do that. I tend to go for solutions that make the most sense though. Look at the requirements of your front-end - what you want to display is one set of data which relate to each other in some way. I would suggest building the back-end logic in such a way that it supports the wishes of the front-end rather than having to implement trickery in the front-end just because your data structure is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you could find what you're searching about , [keeping iteration status](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status)

by simply adding a var after the object , and use index to get the current index value

by example :

```
<div class="row" th:each="v0,iter : ${tables0}" >
    <div class="cell" th:text="value">
        <!-- Here I could display a value from tables0 -->
        <span th:text="${v0}"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="cell"  >
        <span th:text="${table1[iter.index]}"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="cell"  >
        <span th:text="${table2[iter.index]}"></span>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Thymeleaf's `iterStat` to do this.

Assuming the following input data:

```
String[] table0 = {"0", "1", "2", "3"};
String[] table1 = {"14", "21", "25", "75"};
String[] table2 = {"7", "63", "57", "87"};
```

You can use the following Thymeleaf markup:

```
<div class="row" th:each="val,iterStat  : ${table0}" >
    <div class="cell" th:text="${val}">
    </div>
    <div class="cell" th:text="${table1[iterStat.index]}">
    </div>
    <div class="cell" th:text="${table2[iterStat.index]}">
    </div>
</div>
```

This produces a column of numbers as follows (I don't have any CSS so it's just the raw output):

```
0
14
7
1
21
63
2
25
57
3
75
87
```

The related html looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">0</div>
    <div class="cell">14</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">21</div>
    <div class="cell">63</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">25</div>
    <div class="cell">57</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">75</div>
    <div class="cell">87</div>
</div>
```

The `iterStat` function is described [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status) - it basically keeps track of your iterations. Since you want the same index for each table, it's a good fit for your needs.